# iOS : Homekit - How to detect Bluetooth & WiFi service enable in device or not?

Tags: ios, swift, ios10.3, ios-homekit

Home application show the below alert when we are trying to add accessory.

I have also used the HomeKit framwork in my application and want to show the alert when user try to add accessory.

What kind of changes i need to do **to show the same alert in app?**

[Screenshot of Home App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0V9L4.png)

Comment: For Bluetooth: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21696963/4417447 For Wifi Service: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29487450/4417447

Answer (score 0):

For Bluetooth in iOS, you have CBPeripheralManager (in CoreBluetooth Framework). To check for bluetooth connection, you declare your class as delegate of CBPeripheralManager then create a local variable:

```
var myBTManager = CBPeripheralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil, options: nil)
```

then, your class must implement the callback to get noticed when your Bluetooth is enabled or disabled. The code below is extracted from my project which is for Beacon manager

```
//BT Manager
func peripheralManagerDidUpdateState(peripheral: CBPeripheralManager!) {
    println(__FUNCTION__)
    if peripheral.state == CBPeripheralManagerState.PoweredOn {
        println("Broadcasting...")
        //start broadcasting
        myBTManager!.startAdvertising(_broadcastBeaconDict)
    } else if peripheral.state == CBPeripheralManagerState.PoweredOff {
        println("Stopped")
        myBTManager!.stopAdvertising()
    } else if peripheral.state == CBPeripheralManagerState.Unsupported {
        println("Unsupported")
    } else if peripheral.state == CBPeripheralManagerState.Unauthorized {
        println("This option is not allowed by your application")
    }
 }
```

And for Wifi, take a look at this Github: https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift

Source Answer : - [Detecting if Wifi or Bluetooth is turned on or off by the user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28075198/detecting-if-wifi-or-bluetooth-is-turned-on-or-off-by-the-user)