# how to turn on bluetooth force fully or how to ask permission for turn on bluetooth in my ios application

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

```
func centralManagerDidUpdateState(central: CBCentralManager) {
    switch (central.state)
    {
    case .PoweredOff:
        print("off")
    case .PoweredOn:
        centralManager.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(nil, options: nil)
    case .Resetting:
        print("resetting")
    case .Unauthorized:
        print("unaithorized")
    case .Unsupported:
        print("unsupported")
    case .Unknown:
        print("unknown")
    }
}
```

this code only check the status of bluetooth it can not turn on i want to turn on bluetooth at any way

Comment: You can't turn bluetooth on programatically if the user denied your application permissions.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55212803/how-to-show-an-alert-when-turn-off-bluetooth-in-swift-app/55213031#55213031